# GitHub has 16-bit components incompatible with 64-bit Windows 7 OS

Tags: github, windows-7-x64, 16-bit, incompatibility

I just installed GitHub for Windows on my 64-bit Windows 7 computer, and the GitHub always get the following two errors complaining about two components are 16-bit applications incompatible with the 64-bit Windows OS. The two error messages are attached below.

I think there should be many users running GitHub on 64-bit Windows, so could someone please provide some workaround for this issue?

### 1) The first error

### Unsupported 16-Bit Application

The program or feature "\??\C:\Users\mikez\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_054f2e797ebafd44a30203088cd3d58663c627ef\bin\ssh-agent.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibity with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available.

### 2) The second error

### Unsupported 16-Bit Application

The program or feature "\??\C:\Users\mikez\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_054f2e797ebafd44a30203088cd3d58663c627ef\bin\ssh-keygen.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibity with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available.

Comment: And, in this situation, the GitHub cannot work, e.g. the same error will fail cloning and other actions. I think, because the ssh-agent is incompatible with the OS; GitHub's commands cannot be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Give [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) a try. I heard that this works fine.